# Bulk Updates - Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Excel Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforceexcelconnector

I need to do a mass update to all of the email templates in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. From what I've researched, there are no built in app tools do allow this.

I know a popular tool for exporting/importing to Salesforce (not sure which segment it applies to) is Excel Connector, but not sure if that would somehow work for Marketing Cloud.

1. Would the Excel Connector have access to all different segments of Salesforce including the Marketing Cloud?
2. What are other ways one could bulk update email templates in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Salesforce Excel Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Excel_Connector) is to tool that works with **Force.com** (i.e Core Salesforce.com) and not Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Although these platforms are owned by the same company, it is important is recognise that they are very different "under the hood".

Therefore to answer your questions:

1. Would the Excel Connector have access to all different segments of Salesforce including the Marketing Cloud? **NO - to move data between Salesforce.com and Marketing Cloud, look to the Marketing Cloud Connector. This offers some data migration facility, but NOT EMAIL TEMPLATES**
2. What are other ways one could bulk update email templates in Salesforce Marketing Cloud? **You could use the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm) if you are using Classic Content (Email Studio) or [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm) if you are using Content Builder**